# URL Encoding/Decoding in python (whole url, not just the path)

Tags: python, url, urlencode, urllib

I have done a lot of search and experimentation, and I havent been able to find the solution. So, if there is something trivial I missed, I appologize ahead of time.

Problem:

I have a python turbogears app that is downloading url resources. It is being given a URL to download by clients.

One client in particular sends unescaped urls. For eg, 'http://www.foo.com/file with space.txt'

When I try to download it, the download fails, because the server does not recognize this url. It needs to have the spaces escaped to be a valid url.

I know that there are methods ( urllib.urlencode/urllib.quote etc) that will encode strings. However they assume that the strings they work on are not urls. If you give a URL to these methods, they escape the scheme of the url, and make it even more invalid.

So, the summary is: How do I unescape a whole fully qualified url in python?

NOTE: I have tried using urlparse to parse out the url components to get at the path. However sometimes the url will have query parameters, fragments etc. So, I do not want to write code that splits the url into its parts, escapes whatever is required only from the path+query+fragment, and then reconstructs the url.

Is there any helper function that directly takes the url, and escapes it?

Also, note that sometimes I get valid escaped urls from clients. So, I want to handle them as well, without double escaping them.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the following on pypi. This seems to solve the problem.

https://github.com/seomoz/url-py/

This is the url egg from seomoz. Seems to do the job very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to separate the domain name and the file path, then only urlencode the path. [Here's the regex documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), [here's a tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I said above, I prefer not to do that approach. If I want to go that way, I might as well use urlparse to parse out the components, do the change, and compose them back. But then it will be prone to errors.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed that part.